# JobDSL - Create a new job if it doesn't exist in Jenkins already

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I created this Groovy JobDSLs script to generate a new Jenkins jobs.

```
List screen = [["AAA", "Description" ],["AAA", "Description" ]]
for (item in screen) {
    job(item[0]) {
        description(item[1])
        steps {
            shell('command ...')
        }
    }​
}​
```

Is there a way how to tell JobDSL plugin to not create a job in the List, if it already exists in Jenkins? I don't want to keep to separate files for generating new jobs. One file for new jobs and one file for all existing jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a job definition does not change, Job DSL does not update a job.

If a job definition changes and you want to ignore these changes, select the `Action for existing jobs and views: Ignore changes` option in the `Process Job DSLs` build step.

If you are doing this programatically with jobDsl in groovy pipeline, it may look like this:

`jobDsl targets: 'jobs/**/seed.groovy', ignoreExisting: true`

Comment: You are absolutely right @daspilker If job with the same name already exists it persevere history and logs. This code only updates job with the same name if settings are different. This is great, I did not expected, that it will behave desired way naturally.