# How to check if job folder exists in Jenkins from pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I was able to create job folder with below pipeline code

```
folder('project-a') {
    description('Folder for project A')
}
```

but how to check if folder already exists and create only if it doesn't? because this overwrites the existing description.

Comment: does this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285489/jobdsl-create-a-new-job-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-jenkins-already

Comment: Thanks @daggett, yes, I need that, but my pipeline script is under a GUI based job, under `Process Job DSLs` build step, code exactly looks like I have shown above in question, not sure how to use `ignoreExisting` for `folder()` in this case.